# Programmatically shrink HPGL files via Java

Tags: java, file, vector-graphics, file-manipulation

I would need to programmatically (i.e. no human interaction) load HPGL files (coming from third party software) in Java and create a new HPGL file with different proportions (X ratio and Y ratio, passed as parameters to the program)

Let's say that I have the file "One.hpgl" which is a Square (X=1mt Y=1mt). From outside I receive xratio = 90% yratio=110%. I would need to write Java code to produce an output "ModifiedOne.hpgl" which is a Rectangle (X=90cm Y=1.10mt).

Is it feasible in Java?
If so, which is a suggested HPGL library for this kind of work?
I am new to HPGL, so if this is possible, the "shrink/enlargement" should be done once per file or "segment by segment"? I ask because the HPGL files which I should shrink are not simple squares but are more complex drawings and so "shrinking" line by line would be quite difficult.

Thanks for any help you can give me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems not to be a ready-made HPGL parser in Java.

Take a look here: https://github.com/sigram/pcl-parser (limited HPGL, but in Java already)

Also here: http://hpgs.berlios.de/ (more complete HPGL support, but in C)

HPGL references are also available, so you can create a parser from scratch.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will have a look to the resources you gave me